# Unable to replace empty values with 0 in a list of tuples with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which looks like below

```
data = [[('A', 204.593564568), ('B', 217.421341061), ('C', 237.296250326), ('D', 217.464281998), ('E', 206.329901299)], [('F', 210.297625953), ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]]
```

This is just a small part of the data that I have extracted. As you can see, there is no value available for `K`. So I thought. maybe I could use pandas to fix this. So I do this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Dataframe(data).fillna(0)
```

Now I cannot use `df.fillna(0)` since there is no `None` in the data.

So I tried `df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)` which would remove any empty string with a `None` but even this didn't help.

So what can I do to fill the missing data?

**Note:** It is not necessary that I will always receive data in this format. I may also receive in this format as well

```
data = [('F', 210.297625953), ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]
```

What I am looking for is a generic solution in pandas to fill the missing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
In [299]: data = [('F', 210.297625953), ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]           

In [300]: pd.DataFrame(data).fillna(0).to_records(index=False).tolist()                                         
Out[300]: 
[('F', 210.297625953),
 ('G', 228.117692718),
 ('H', 4.0),
 ('I', 265.319671257),
 ('K', 0.0)]
```

---

For the case with nested lists:

```
In [308]: data = [[('A', 204.593564568), ('B', 217.421341061), ('C', 237.296250326), ('D', 217.464281998), ('E',
     ...:  206.329901299)], [('F', 210.297625953), ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]
     ...: ]                                                                                                     

In [309]: from itertools import chain                                                                           

In [310]: pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(data)).fillna(0).to_records(index=False).tolist()                    
Out[310]: 
[('A', 204.593564568),
 ('B', 217.421341061),
 ('C', 237.296250326),
 ('D', 217.464281998),
 ('E', 206.329901299),
 ('F', 210.297625953),
 ('G', 228.117692718),
 ('H', 4.0),
 ('I', 265.319671257),
 ('K', 0.0)]
```

Answer (score 4):

use [pd.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df.applymap(lambda x: (x[0],0) if len(x) == 1 else x)
```

---

```
                    0                   1                   2  \
0  (A, 204.593564568)  (B, 217.421341061)  (C, 237.296250326)   
1  (F, 210.297625953)  (G, 228.117692718)              (H, 4)   

                    3                   4  
0  (D, 217.464281998)  (E, 206.329901299)  
1  (I, 265.319671257)              (K, 0)
```

**Alternative**..since edit

why dont you flatten your tuples, see below (using [np.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html))

```
data = list(np.array(data).flatten()) #since it can be list of list or a list
##data
[('A', 204.593564568),
 ('B', 217.421341061),
 ('C', 237.296250326),
 ('D', 217.464281998),
 ('E', 206.329901299),
 ('F', 210.297625953),
 ('G', 228.117692718),
 ('H', 4),
 ('I', 265.319671257),
 ('K',)]
```

and then,

```
pd.DataFrame(data).fillna(0)
```

---

```
   0           1
0  A  204.593565
1  B  217.421341
2  C  237.296250
3  D  217.464282
4  E  206.329901
5  F  210.297626
6  G  228.117693
7  H    4.000000
8  I  265.319671
9  K    0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem properly you can add `None` using next list comprehension:

```
data = [[('A', 204.593564568), ('B', 217.421341061), ('C', 237.296250326), ('D', 217.464281998), ('E', 206.329901299)], [('F', 210.297625953), ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]]
new_data = [[t if len(t) == 2 else (*t, None) for t in l] for l in data]
```

Comment: Beat me to it. If you want to apply it to your dataframe, just do `df = df.apply(lambda S:[x if len(x) == 2 else (*x, None) for x in S])`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you may have either a list or a list of list, if so, try a func:

```
data1=[[('A', 204.593564568), ('B', 217.421341061), ('C', 237.296250326), 
 ('D', 217.464281998), ('E', 206.329901299)], [('F', 210.297625953), 
       ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]]
data2 = [('F', 210.297625953), ('G', 228.117692718), ('H', 4), ('I', 265.319671257), ('K',)]
```

---

```
import itertools
def myfunc(x):
    if type(x[0])==list:
       return pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)).fillna(0)
    else:
       return pd.DataFrame(x).fillna(0)
```

---

```
print(myfunc(data1))
```

---

```
   0           1
0  A  204.593565
1  B  217.421341
2  C  237.296250
3  D  217.464282
4  E  206.329901
5  F  210.297626
6  G  228.117693
7  H    4.000000
8  I  265.319671
9  K    0.000000
```

---

```
print(myfunc(data2))
```

---

```
   0           1
0  F  210.297626
1  G  228.117693
2  H    4.000000
3  I  265.319671
4  K    0.000000
```